# How to use the list made in background thread in UI thread?

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a very long list which is being made in background thread. I want to use the list in adapter to populate it in the listview. How should I communicate to the UI thread when the list is complete..
I am using the code below:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    getAllSaudaEntry();
                }
            });
            t.start();

adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), LongList,R.layout.sauda_row, from, to);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

public void getAllSaudaEntry(){
        db = dbh.getReadableDatabase();

map = new HashMap<String, String>();
.
.
.
LongList.add(map);
```

I have heard about notifyDatasetChanged(). Where shouid I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways this could be done. Whatever you do, though, don't set the adapter from the worker thread.

### 1. AsyncQueryHandler

If your data is in a content provider, this is probably the easiest way to go. It takes care of pretty much all the dirty work for you and comes back with a callback when it's done. Looking at your code, it doesn't seem like you're using a content provider, but I wanted to point it out for completeness' sake. (And as a side note - you may want to look into using one. I know the android docs say you only really need one if you're sharing data with other applications, but if you don't, you'll miss out on a lot of the SDK's conveniences such as `Loader`s).

### 2. AsyncTask

You can also use an `AsyncTask` to do the heavy lifting on a different thread (in the `doInBackground` method), then pass the populated list to `onPostExecute` to set it on the list. `onPostExecute` runs on the UI thread.

### 3. Handler

Attach a custom `Handler` to the UI thread. When your calculation thread is done, pass a message from it to that Handler that contains the populated list as a parameter (its `obj`). Your handler can then decode the message, retrieve the list, and set it on the adapter.

Doing this involves the following steps:

```
handler = new Handler(null, new Handler.Callback() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Map result = (Map) msg.obj;
        LongList.add(map);
        adapter(new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), LongList,R.layout.sauda_row, from, to);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Then in your worker thread, when your calculations are complete, go like:

```
Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
msg.obj = yourResultMap;
msg.sendToTarget();
```

## Which way should you go?

If I were you, I'd go with the AsyncTask. Why? Well, my first choice would usually be AsyncQueryHandler, but this is out if you don't use a content provider. That leaves Handler and AsyncTask. Handler is a powerful tool, but its best suited where a lot of communication has to happen between your worker thread and the UI thread. In your case, you really only have two messages that ever need to be passed - the implicit start message, and then your result message. This is the perfect setup for an AsyncTask.

Javadocs you might want to read:
AsyncQueryHandler, AsyncTask, Handler, Message

Comment: Thanks @cris but I would like to go for Handler. Can you explain me How can I use handler in this situation.

Comment: @donison24x7 I've edited my answer to address your comment. However, `Handler` is really a bit of overkill for you. It's at its best when there are lots of messages to be passed back and forth, you really just have one you want to send explicitly.

Comment: Show stacktrace and indicate line in source please

Comment: Whoa! it worked.... and working fine. Thanks cris, thankyou very much.
 that was eclipse problem

Answer (score 2):

After set your adapter you have to call it.

```
 adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), LongList,R.layout.sauda_row, from, to);
 listView.setAdapter(adapter);
 adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
```

Comment: @Rajendra... SQLiteException: unable to close due to unfinalised statements.
I think is is due to the above Thread t and the adapter.notifyDatasetChanged(); is running parallelly.(at same time)

Comment: The problem because you haven't close your database properly.

Comment: I closed at the end of my method getAllSaudaEntry(). whwere should I do it. I am a newbie..